# Change the font face in "Completed!" text

Tags: fonts, font-face

I was trying to make a website out of this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6auzdmxVC4

Here is the loading I did:

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:200px; height:50">
</progress>
<span id="status">
</span>
<h1 id="finalMessage">
</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function progressBarSim(al) {
var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = al+"%";
bar.value = al;
al++;
var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim("+al+")",70);
if(al == 100){
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 100;
    clearTimeout(sim);
    document.getElementById('finalMessage').innerHTML = "Completed!";
}
```

> }
>
> var amountLoaded = 0;
>   progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
>   < /script>

(remove space in script closing tag)

But surprisingly. I need to change the font face of the "Completed!" text. Can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same routine to change the font-face in the CSS.

Comment: Like suggested above, or like this:  document.getElementById("finalMessage").style.font="italic bold 20px arial,serif";

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('finalMessage').innerHTML = "<div style='font-size:20px'>Completed!</div>";
```